# Multiple levels of NGINX Reverse Proxy: one at router gateway level and another on each LXD Server Environment?

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, lxd

I've been using nginx as a reverse proxy in my home lab for quite a while.  Lets Encrypt as well.  All is well there.

But now I am adding in the concept of LXD containers and I've hit a problem.

If I have an LXD server, then I need a proxy to bridge the network traffic to the LXD domain machines on that server.

If I already have an nginx proxy at my router gateway level, is it possible to have two levels of proxying?

Do I copy/paste the certs that Lets Encrpt created on my router gateway level onto the LXD server and just use the proxy protocol to pass things along?

Thanks for any advice.

[image]